# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor Pages Bad Request when calling Handler via Javascript Fetch on Post, but NOT Get

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fetch, razor-pages

I have 2 simple fetch calls to handlers.  The Get request works, the Post returns 400. What am I missing?

Javascript:

```
fetch(
    'UploadFile/?handler=Test1', { method: 'GET' })
    .then((response) => {
        return response.text();
    })
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    });

fetch(
    'UploadFile/?handler=Test2', { method: 'POST' })
    .then((response) => {
        return response.text();
    })
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Code Behind:

```
    public JsonResult OnGetTest1()
    {
        return new JsonResult(new { Result = "Test1" });
    }

    public JsonResult OnPostTest2()
    {
        return new JsonResult(new { Result = "Test2" });
    }
```

Comment: Razor Pages enforces CSRF protection for POST handlers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery.

Comment: Am I the first person to try to post a fetch request from a Razor page? I can't find any examples online.

Comment: Using the example from the link supplied, the code won't compile:( Any idea what the full namespace for the 'Context' object is?

Comment: @inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf
@functions{
    public string GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()
    {
        return Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(Context).RequestToken;
    }
}

Comment: Adding: @Html.AntiForgeryToken() solved the problem. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @Kirk Larkin.

Comment: One more quick question if you don't mind. I haven't figured out the nuances of Stackoverflow yet. How can I correctly reference a user in comments. How can I add a line break in comments?

Comment: Type the @ symbol in the comment box, followed by the user name - it should autocomplete. Sadly, you can't do linebreaks in comments.